A combinatoric problem about team-based Mahjong tournament
In a team-based Mahjong tournament, there are $n$ teams, each having $m$ members, where $m, n \geq 4$. Each Mahjong game requires $4$ players to play.
For each game, $4$ players from distinct teams are selected, i.e., one from each of $4$ distinct teams.
Consider the following requirements:

each of the $mn$ players should play the same number of games
for any two teams, the number of times that they are selected to play in the same game should be the same

Questions

For what positive integers $m, n \geq 4$ is it possible to have a tournament that satisfies the two requirements?
If possible, what is the minimum number of total games that satisfies the two requirements?


For question $1$, I think it is obviously possible for all $m,n\ge 4$. If you have a Mahjong game using all possible ways of choosing four players from distinct teams, then your symmetry requirements are satisfied. Question $2$ is still interesting.

Finding a Mahjong tournament with these constraints is equivalent to finding a certain balanced incomplete block design (BIBD), or just block design for short. A block design consists of a set $V$, together with a collection of subsets of $V$ called blocks, such that each block contains the same number of elements, and that each pair of elements of $V$ appear together in the same number of blocks. Given integers $v,k,$ and $\lambda$, the notation $\text{BIBD}(v,k,\lambda)$ refers to a block design on a set of $v$ elements, where each block has size $k$, and each pair of elements appears together in $\lambda$ blocks.
In this case, $v=n$, and the underlying set is the set of $n$ teams (not the set of $m\cdot n$ people). Each Mahjong game corresponds to a set of $4$ teams, so the size of each block is $k=4$. Therefore, if each pair of teams play together $\lambda$ times, then choosing the teams for each game is equivalent to choosing a $\text{BIBD}(n,4,\lambda)$. For such a design, the total number of Mahjong games will be $\lambda\cdot \frac{n(n-1)}{12}$, so in order to have the fewest number of games, you want $\lambda$ to be as small as possible.
In order for every player to play an equal number of games, the number of games that each team participates in must be a multiple of $m$. For any block design with parameters $(v,k,\lambda)$, the number of blocks containing each element is always $\lambda\cdot \frac{v-1}{k-1}$. Therefore, we get the following constraint:

$\lambda\cdot \frac{n-1}3$ must be a multiple of $m$.

Therefore, to answer your question fully, you need to know exactly when a $\text{BIBD}(n,4,\lambda)$ exists. The existence of block designs with block size $4$ is fully characterized by Hanani in the paper below. Hanani proved that $\text{BIBD}(n,4,\lambda)$ exists if and only if at least one of these conditions is met:

$n\equiv 1$ or $4\pmod {12}$,

$n\equiv 1\pmod 3$, and $\lambda$ is a multiple of $2$.

$n\equiv 0$ or $1\pmod 4$, and $\lambda$ is a multiple of $3$.

$\lambda$ is a multiple of $6$.


In conclusion, given inputs $n$ and $m$, your question is answered by finding the smallest value of $\lambda$ which satisfies all of the constraints above, and then constructing that $\text{BIBD}(n,4,\lambda)$. To find out how to actually construct the BIBD, you will either need to consult the Hanani paper, or refer to my earlier answer (see the Constructions section).

Haim Hanani, Balanced incomplete block designs and related designs, Discrete Mathematics, Volume 11, Issue 3, 1975, Pages 255-369, ISSN 0012-365X, https://doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(75)90040-0.


If there are only 4 teams, isn't $m$ games enough, as in, each player plays exactly once? Or did I miss something?

@user141240 I was confused before, but I have now edited my answer, and it should completely answer your question.
